# Ionic - CSS issues Android and iOS devices

Tags: android, ios, css, ionic-framework

I am facing many CSS issues when deploying my Ionic Project to iPhone. It works fine on Android Devices (Nexus, Samsung etc). I have tried many things but won't able to come up with a solution. For eg one of my issues:

```
div {
overflow-x:auto;
}
```

Works completely fine on Android devices, but my scroll won't work on iPhone. One more problem I am facing is Side Menu bug on iPhone, i.e *When swipe-right 1 time everything is gone but a blank screen of my background-color, but when I swipe-left 2 more times Side Menu appears*. This is working fine on Android devices. Thank you.

Comment: You need to be more specific with the code you are using in the functionality that is not working